# Jquery: hide all table columns only if all its value is "NA"

Tags: javascript, jquery

For eg.

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5   col6  
1        pass   NA      Pass    NA     NA  
2        pass   NA      pass    NA     pass  
3        fail   NA      pass    NA     NA
```

Then hide col3 and col5. Resulting table is below:

```
col1    col2    col4      
1        pass   Pass      
2        pass   pass      
3        fail   pass
```

col3 and col5 is hidden now.

Note : I am populating all rows through ajax. For each rows ajax is triggered.

Here is my existing code:

```
function hideOneValueColumns(table_id, ignore_row_class, ignore_column_class) {

    var row_count = $('#' + table_id + ' tr:not(.' + ignore_row_class + ')').length;
    if (row_count > 2) {

        //first go through the column headers
        $('#' + table_id + ' th').each(function (i) {
            //only process the column if it isn't one of the column we should ignore
            if (!$(this).hasClass(ignore_column_class)) {
                //get all cells of the columns (in order to show or hide them)
                var all_cells = $(this).parents('table').find('tr td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
                //get the cells we'll use to decide whether we want to filter the column or not
                var filtered_cells = $(this).parents('table').find('tr:not(.' + ignore_row_class + ') td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');

                //array containing the list of different values in a column
                var values = new Array();
                //gather the different cell values
                filtered_cells.each(function () {
                    var value = this.innerHTML;
                 // gather all cells which has values NA
                    if (values == 'NA') {
                        values.push(value);
                    }
                });
                //hide if less than 2 different values and show if at least 2 different values
                if (values.length == $('#' + table_id + ' tr').length) {
                    $(this).hide();
                    all_cells.hide();
                } else {
                    $(this).show();
                    all_cells.show();
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#' + table_id + ' th').show();
        $('#' + table_id + ' tr td').show();
    }
}
// call the method
// spcl is table id
hideOneValueColumns('spcl', 'filters', 'no-hide');
```

Comment: what you get on these two consoles `console.log(values.length); console.log($('#'+table_id+' tr').length);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over each table row and, for each column, work out if the cell contains 'NA'. If it does not, then leave the entire column alone.

In this code snippet I get the number of columns from the first row (assuming them to be row headers). Then, for each number of columns, for each row, get that column. The default functionality I have done here is to `hide` the column. If any of the cells in the column does not contain `NA`, then `show` the column.

```js
"use strict";
function hideOneValueColumns(table_id) {
  var columnCount = jQuery('#'+table_id+' tr:first-of-type th').length + 1;

  for(var i = 1; i < columnCount; i++) {
    var func = 'hide';
    jQuery('tr:not(:first-of-type)').each(function(){
      var $td = jQuery(this).find('td:nth-child('+i+')');
      if($td.text() != 'NA') {
        func = 'show';
      }
    });
    jQuery('tr td:nth-child('+i+'), tr th:nth-child('+i+')')[func]();
  }
}

hideOneValueColumns('some_id');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="some_id">
  <tr>
    <th>col1</th>
    <th>col2</th>
    <th>col3</th>
    <th>col4</th>
    <th>col5</th>
    <th>col6</th>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>pass</td><td>NA</td><td>Pass</td><td>NA</td><td>NA</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>pass</td><td>NA</td><td>pass</td><td>NA</td><td>Pass</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>fail</td><td>NA</td><td>pass</td><td>NA</td><td>NA</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I need to hide columns only when all its values is 'NA'. Please look into question description. col3 and col5 gets hidden but not col6